# Android How do you get total memory RAM in the device?

Tags: android, api, memory

I can get total available memory by:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
memoryInfo.availMem;
```

However, how do you get Total memory (RAM) of the device?

I did read:
[How do I discover memory usage of my application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android)

It doesn't seem like adding pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPss() gives me the total memory either.

Comment: I guess you can do this way 'memoryInfo.totalMem'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this works for me.

```
public static String getTotalRAM() {
    RandomAccessFile reader = null;
    String load = null;
    try {
        reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/meminfo", "r");
        load = reader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Streams.close(reader);
    }
    return load;
}
```

Comment: no this is not give any memory size of RAM dude its print then read string object like "reader is == java.io.RandomAccessFile@413b39c0"

Comment: why comment out the cleanup?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't find something else, you could bypass android and read /proc/meminfo which is what the 'free' command on a more ordinary linux distribution does

Answer (score 3):

MemoryInfo class has added totalMem in API 16. Please give a try.

public long totalMem
Added in API level 16
The total memory accessible by the kernel. This is basically the RAM size of the device, not including below-kernel fixed allocations like DMA buffers, RAM for the baseband CPU, etc.